# What was the bright orange glow in the sky?

Tags: observational-astronomy

[image: orange night glow]
It moved then disappeared. What was it?

Comment: Mars is bright, and orange.  However it doesn't move or disappear.  Nothing astronomical can be said to move or disappear, so this most likely a plane, or similar.  We can't identify flying objects.

Comment: Which glow. Do you mean the Mars-like object, or that background glow in the low sky? If the little object, then it's almost certainly Mars, and you moved, or an aeroplane if you didn't. If you mean the glow, various options, none connected with Astronomy.

Comment: Hello! Could you please add some further information. For example: When the photo was taken/the event was observed, where you were and in which direction you looked, a more detailed description of the motion etc. Thanks!

Comment: The pic was taken only with my mobile phone on Friday night. I watched the orange glow move slowly with my own eyes then just disappears. It seemed to be travelling west. It was quite mesmerising to watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is low on the horizon and there is glow from distant lights.

I have seen stars or planets suddenly disappear when fairly low, and it happens when clouds that were not visible at night move in between the object and myself.

If there is some hazy glow already in the sky, and the cloud is darker, it could be completely invisible and undetectable until it blocks something.

If it move just a tiny bit, it could be that the viewer moved and the the movement relative to the branches is what was actually seen. Assuming its a star or planet it would not have moved quickly in the sky, but relative to foreground objects for reference if one's head moves slightly it could have *seemed to move*.